# The correct way of using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

The idea is to use less connection and better performance.
Does the connection expire at any time?

And for another question, does `_redis.GetDatabase()` open new connection?

```
private static ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
private static IDatabase _db;

public RedisCacheProvider(string configuration)
{
    if (_redis == null)
        lock (myLock)
            if (_redis == null)
            {
                _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
                _db = _redis.GetDatabase();
            }
}

public async Task<string> GetString(string key)
{
    string result = null;

    RedisValue val = await _db.StringGetAsync(key);

    if (val.HasValue)
        result = val;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, a multiplexer doesn't expire. No GetDatabase doesn't open a new connection. This is all covered in [basics.md](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Basics.md) - in particular:

> The object returned from GetDatabase is a cheap pass-thru object, and does not need to be stored.

Comment: Is there a performance impact by using a static IDatabase object vs calling GetDatabase every time you need to call one of it's methods?

Comment: @Aaron for db 0-15 and without an async state, in recent builds: not at all. (note: `.GetDatabase()` is db 0 without an async-state, so: no overhead).  For older builds, dbs above 15, or with an async-state: minimal - a single object is allocated

Comment: @MarcGravell Would you please elaborate a bit about "cheap pass-thru object"? What does it _actually_ mean?

Comment: @tehmas I mean that it is simply a token class that carries the multiplexer, chosen database number, and (rarely) state object; for "low" database numbers (for my arbitrary definition of low), there's a good chance it'll also be memoized at the multiplexer level, i.e. if you call `GetDatabase(2)` 3 times, you'll probably get the same object 3 times, not 3 different objects; but either way: it doesn't need to *do* anything - calling `GetDatabase` doesn't talk to the server, etc

Comment: If `GetDatabase` doesn't actually talk to the server, why I am able to get a `timeout` exception just by calling a method (which just calls `GetDatabase`) multiple times in parallel? Please note I am also using a single redis connection using lazy loading.

Comment: @tehmas I'd need to see code; short version is: you can't, so I expect the problem is in your test rig; [here's the code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs#L1182-L1193) - as you can see, other than validating the args, it doesn't do anything except either return a pre-existing instance, or a new simple object

Comment: @tehmas and in case you're wondering "does the constructor talk to the multiplexer" - no: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L12-L16 and https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisBase.cs#L13-L17