# Should `StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer` be `AddSingleton` or `AddScope` in .NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: redis, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I'm adding a Redis connection to .NET Core using `StackExchange.Redis`, it currently looks something like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRedisMultiplexer(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Func<ConfigurationOptions> getOptions = null)
{
    // Get the options or assume localhost, as these will be set in Startup.ConfigureServices assume they won't change
    var options = getOptions?.Invoke() ?? ConfigurationOptions.Parse("localhost");

    // The Redis is a singleton, shared as much as possible.
    return services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(provider => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options));
}
```

Then in `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRedisMultiplexer(() => 
        ConfigurationOptions.Parse(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Redis"]));
    ...
```

This then means I can use `IConnectionMultiplexer` for the dependency injection anywhere.

My question is: `ConnectionMultiplexer` is [designed to be reused](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/docs/Basics.md), so I've used `AddSingleton` to keep a single instance for the entire application. However I could also use `AddScoped` to use one for the duration of the request. Which is better and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is the load expected to the app ? If you have much concurrency, I think using `AddScoped` would mean a lot of unnecessary burden to initiate and close connections for every request.

Also these observations IMHO show that you should use `AddSingleton`

> (...) it is exceptionally rare that you would want to use a
>   ConnectionMultiplexer briefly, as the idea is to re-use this object.
>
> Another common use of redis is as a pub/sub message distribution tool;
>   this is also simple, and **in the event of connection failure, the
>   ConnectionMultiplexer will handle all the details of re-subscribing to
>   the requested channels.**

Also, you will save memory having only one instance of `ConnectionMultiplexer` (IMHO).

Comment: The app needs to scale, but I'm not expecting huge number of concurrent requests. My opinion is to use `AddSingleton` too, but I'm fairly new to using `StackExchange.Redis` and a little unsure just how much to reuse the multiplexer.

Comment: @Keith The multiplexer seems to even handle multiple instances of Redis (master/slave) just by passing the connection URLs, so I think this is a good choice.