# StackExchange.Redis dependency injection of IDatabase?

Tags: c#, .net-5, stackexchange.redis

So [according to StackExchange.Redis docs](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics), I am to re-use `IConnectionMultiplexer`.

```csharp
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(
        ConnectionMultiplexer
              .Connect($"{configsOptions.RedisUrl},password={secretsOptions.RedisPassword}"));
```

But then I found that in my redis service method, I'd have to inject the IConnectionMultiplexer and then connect to the database like this:

```csharp
public Task GetSomethingFromRedis(string key)
{
    IDatabase db = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
    string value = db.StringGet(key);
}
```

Instead of calling `connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase()` every time, is OK for me to have a **Singleton** of the `IDatabase` object, injected like this? Or is this a really bad idea?

```csharp
services.AddSingleton<IDatabase>(cfg =>
   {
         var redisConnection = 
         ConnectionMultiplexer
            .Connect($"{configsOptions.RedisUrl},password={secretsOptions.RedisPassword}");

         return redisConnection.GetDatabase();
   });
```

Comment: "he object returned from GetDatabase is a cheap pass-thru object, and does not need to be stored." so it seems like something that you would create every time no?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849257/4122889

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```csharp
services.AddScoped<IDatabase>(cfg =>
     {
         IConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{configsOptions.RedisUrl},password={secretsOptions.RedisPassword}");
         return multiplexer.GetDatabase();
     });
```

And then in my service:

```csharp
private readonly IDatabase cache;

public RedisService(IDatabase cache)
{
   this.cache = cache;
}
```

Comment: This works, full stop. But the docs state _The object returned from GetDatabase is a cheap pass-thru object, and does not need to be stored._ This means you can use `AddScoped<IConnectionMultiplexer>` and simply return the created `ConnectionMultiplexer`. 

And maybe it's even better to instantiate it as a singleton per these docs: 'Because the ConnectionMultiplexer does a lot, it is designed to be shared and reused between callers. You should not create a ConnectionMultiplexer per operation.'

Source: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics